# How to deploy multiple stack with one template in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, stack, aws-cloudformation

Is their any way to deploy multiple stack such as (Network stack, ec2 stack, dbstack) with a single stack in cloudformation.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormation supports “nested stacks”, which you can use you deploy multiple templates as you describe.

You can read more about nested stacks in the AWS CloudFormation documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write separate stack for each of the services like ec2, DB, VPC then you have to go with a configuration management tool like Ansible.

Writing up multiple plays and calling stack using cloud formation module. [Example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cloudformation_module.html)